UserForm is blank when I opened
When I click the open form button I want the current data to display automatically. It used to work correctly but just stopped. Not sure what happened or where I went wrong.
opens the userform
Sub Button8_Click()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub

should display data as soon as opened
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()

TBITEMNUMBER.Value = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A3").Value
COLORS.Value = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B3").Value
ITEMDESCRIPTION.Value = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C3").Value
DESCRIPTION2.Value = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C3").Value
SEARCHWORDS.Value = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("D3").Value
 

Everything I found on-line says to set it up exactly how I already have it.  So not sure what caused it to quit working.

If no any error, did you check if the active workbook has these values in the cells where from you try extracting? Since the ranges are not fully qualified, your code works on the active workbook.

The event name is UserForm_Initialize, no matter what the name of the userform is.

Have you set a Breakpoint at the start of the code so that you can see what values are being passed in and if the code is even being called?  Debugging Code 101 is to step into your code and set watches to confirm the values are what you expect and that the code is being executed.

The event name is UserForm_Initialize, no matter what the name of the userform is... that was the issue. Thank you!!

Event routines for a VBA userform are identified by the name. This name contains two parts, the first identifies the object, the second the event. Events for a control (e.g. a button) get the name of the control (CommandButton1) plus the event name, e.g. Click. The event name is CommandButton1_Click.
As a consequence, when you rename a control (from CommandButton1 to btnOK), you need to rename the event routine (to btnOK_Click), else the VBA runtime will not find it.
However, the event routines for a userform are named Userform_ plus the event name, eg UserForm_Initialize. This is independent of the user form name (which is a class name, to be precise).
To help you to avoid errors in event name:
When you are in the form editor and make a double click on a control, the VBA editor will jump to the default event of the control. For buttons, this is the Click-event, for text boxes the Change-event (for a form it's also the Click-event which is a little bit useless...). If the routine doesn't yet exist, the VBA editor will create an empty event handler, with the correct name and the correct parameters (if any).
But you can let the VBA editor create the event routines that are not the default: From the left dropdown above the code editor, select the control, or, for the form itself, "Userform". Now from the right dropdown, select the event, eg "Initialize".

This will create an empty routine for you:

If you are in doubt if an event routine is called or not, simply set a breakpoint to the top of the routine and check if the line is hit. Then trigger the event (press a button, show the form...). If the code doesn't stop, most likely the event routine has a wrong name.
